# Adding datagridview to tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code creating datagridview named dgv with each step of the loop. I want to add that datagridview to tabControl, but it adds without content in it. What's the problem with content? And why Controls.Add(dgv) works fine and dgv has content in it?

```
 DataGridView dgv = null;
            Matrix[] d = new Matrix[crits];
            for (int c = 0; c < crits; c++)
            {
                Matrix mat = new Matrix(alts, alts);
                for (int i = 0; i < alts; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < alts; j++)
                        mat[i, j] = critMat[i, c] - critMat[j, c];

                dgv = new DataGridView();

                dgv.ColumnCount = alts + 1;
                dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
                dgv.RowCount = alts + 1;
                dgv[0, 0].Value = "Критерий" + c;
                for (int i = 1; i <= alts; i++)
                    dgv[0, i].Value = dgv[i, 0].Value = dgvInput[0, i - 1].Value;


                for (int i = 0; i < alts; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < alts; j++)
                        dgv[j + 1, i + 1].Value = mat[i, j];

            tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Критерий " + c);
            tabControl1.TabPages[c].Controls.Add(dgv);
            }
```

Comment: @S.Ak: It isn't data bound, from what I see.

Comment: A __TabControl can only contain TabPages__. So, what is working and what isn't??

Comment: @TaW So basically I want to add datagridview to tabcontrol. Everything works fine except if I add dgv to tabpage it addes without content in it. I checked if dgv stuff even works, using Controls.Add(dgv) and it works just the way it should, but to tabPages it only adds empty datagridview, without any cells

Comment: I can't reproduce.

Comment: @TaW. Ok. Why it is working like that: this.Controls.Add(dgv) works fine, it adds to the form dgv, that contains results of some calculations. But when I try "tabControl1.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(dgv)" it adds just empty dgv to tabpage?

Comment: Most likely `i` points to the wrong page. It works fine here; best set the `Name` property to the new page `tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new TabPage("Критерий " + c") { Name = "Критерий " + c });` and use it to acces the page: `tabControl1.TabPages["Критерий " + c].Controls.Add(dgv);`. Note the string fed into the `Add` call is only the `Text`, not the `Name` of the page!!!